# Thymeleaf recursion not working

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a recursive list using Thymeleaf. I'm using a simple Java object to model a node which has has two fields, a description and then an array list of child nodes. I'm using the following HTML/Thymeleaf to process the structure but it isn't recursively iterating through to the next level down.

My Java code looks as follows:

```
public class Node {
    public String description;
    public ArrayList<Node> children;
}
```

My Thymeleaf/HTML code is as follows:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <div th:fragment="fragment_node" th:remove="tag">
            <ul th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(node.children)}" >
                <li th:each="child : ${node.children}"
                    th:text="${child.description}"
                    th:with="node = ${child}"
                    th:include="this::fragment_node">List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If my data structure looks as follows:

- Main node 1

  - Child node 1
  - Child node 2
- Main node 2

  - Child node 3
  - Child node 4

I'd expect to get:

```
<ul>
    <li>Main Node 1</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Child node 1</li>
            <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Node 2</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Child node 3</li>
            <li>Child node 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I only get:

```
<ul>
    <li>Main Node 1</li>
    <li>Main Node 2</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone spot why this may not be working?

Comment: Have the child children? have you try to simplify it a little bit? Try to extract the include in the `li` and put the following in `<div th:with="child = ${child}" th:include="this::fragment_node" th:remove="tag" />`.

Answer (score 2):

**The cause of the problem is**

You are trying to `th:text` and trying to add the description to a `<li>` as well as you are trying to `th:include` the fragment inside the same tag `<li>`.

Your `th:include` is replaced by the `th:text` as `th:text` is processed with priority by default.

**Direct solution to your source code**

```
 .....
 <li th:each="child : ${node.children}" th:inline="text" th:with="node = ${child}">
      [[${child.description}]]
      <ul th:replace="this::fragment_node">List Item</ul>
 </li>
 .....
```

Even thought the above will work as you want, personally I find some design issues in your thymeleaf page.

**Better solution using fragment parameters**

```
 ...
 <ul th:fragment="fragment_node(node)" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(node.children)}" >
     <li th:each="child : ${node.children}" th:inline="text">
         [[${child.description}]]
         <ul th:replace="this::fragment_node(${child})"></ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
 ...
```

Comment: Really useful answer